# CQRS file upload/data manipulation

Tags: cqrs

how do you handle data manipulation in CQRS? I'm thinking about command, which have byte array (or inputstream) field. Then in commandhandler
I can process file (save it to filesystem) and send event, where would be the path to the saved file. Is this approach ok, or should I use something different?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

CQRS is silent on the topic of 'data manipulation' except to say that the 'write side' of the application should be separate from the 'read side'. There is no defined practice, and it will depend very much on your domain.

Does your domain contain the concepts of 'files' and 'byte arrays'? Probably not, so it sounds as if you are building an anti-corruption layer which validates and translates an external source of data into commands to be issued against your domain.

Comment: And is it ok to put the logic to the anti-corruption layer? business logic="The data should be placed somewhere based on something" I expect that anti-corruption layer is another "service layer" where I can transform "outer message" to "inner message" aka command.

Comment: @bilak Well it's difficult to say without knowing the domain. But ACLs do as their name implies - protect the domain from commands that originate outside the context. If your business logic is something implicit inside the context but must be stated explicitly outside the context, then it needs to live in the ACL.